# accordion using jquery div should be closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

below is the code for accordion and i want the page loads all the divisions closed by default and when i click on particular division it will open and when i click on other division it  will open and previous one closes automatically.
**NOTE** it should be compatible with the ie8.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!--  <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="accord.js"></script>
    <style>
        .wrap {
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            width: 100px;
        }

        .accordion1 {
            width: 178px;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            list-style: none;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

            .accordion1 h2 {
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                margin: 0px;
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: .25em .25em .25em 2em;
                color: #333;
                background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_gray.gif') repeat-x;
                background: url("./compo_images/arrow_exp_s.gif") 1em .75em no-repeat;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

                .accordion1 h2:hover {
                    background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_orange.gif') repeat-x;
                    color: white;
                }

            .accordion1 li div.content {
                padding: 3px;
                background: #fcfbfb;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
                /*border: 1px solid #ddd;*/
            }

            .accordion1 li:hover h2 {
                color: white;
                background-image: url("./compo_images/arrow_exp_n.gif");
                background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_orange.gif') repeat-x;
            }

        .accord > li {
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }

            .accord > li > a {
                text-decoration: none;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                padding-left: 12px;
                color: #5f5c5c;
                background: url("./compo_images/arrow_pointer_se.gif") 0.002em no-repeat;
            }

            .accord > li > ul > li > a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #5f5c5c;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 11px;
                background: url("./compo_images/arrow_dirmini_orange_e.gif") 0.35em no-repeat;
                padding-left: 17px;
            }

            .accord > li > ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                text-align: left;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 1px;
            }

        .accord {
            text-decoration: none;
            padding-left: 5px;
        }

            .accord > li > a:hover {
                color: #f8b106;
            }

            .accord > li > ul > li > a:hover {
                color: #f8b106;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrap">

        <ul class="accordion1">
            <li>
                <h2 id="first">CMT</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    <ul class="accord">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">main link1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Five</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">main link2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Five</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>FOIS</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    content fois
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>ASP</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    content ASP
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>PTT</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    content PTT
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- wrap -->
</body>
</html>
```

below is `accord.js`

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.accord li').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideDown()
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideUp()
    }).find('ul').hide()

})
```

Comment: the problem is the  all the divisions are open but i want close also when i click on CMT its division will open and when i click on another division it will open and previous division closes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var $lis = $('.accordion1 > li'), $contents = $lis.children('.content').hide();
$lis.children('h2').click(function(){
    var $t = $(this).next();
    $contents.not($t).stop(true, true).slideUp();
    $t.slideToggle();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sTLAZ/)

Comment: thanks for the help ,one thing i want to implement whichever tab is active its header color should get changes to orange color.can you please tell me how to do that?